# How to use the equivalent circuit of an induction motor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, datasheet, three-phase, induction-motor, phasor

I have met a data sheet for a three phase induction motor intended for the traction
applications. The data sheet contains below given table

[image]

I have chosen the column *operating point - continuous point A* and I have attempted
to solve the T-equivalent circuit based on the given values of the resistances and
reactances

[image]

I have prepared a below given *Scilab* script for this purpose

```
VS  = 420/sqrt(3);               // nominal per phase stator voltage (V)
fs  = 60;                        // frequency (Hz)
s   = 0.0248;                    // nominal slip (-)
pp  = 2;                         // number of pole pairs (-)
    
Rs  = 16.3*10^(-3);              // stator resistance (Ohm)
Lm  = 2.581/(2*%pi*fs);          // magnetizing inductance (Henry)
Lls = (77.7*10^(-3))/(2*%pi*fs); // stator leakage inductance (Henry)
Ls  = Lls + Lm;                  // stator inductance (Henry)
Rr  = 12.8*10^(-3);              // rotor resistance (Ohm)
Llr = (60.6*10^(-3))/(2*%pi*fs); // rotor leakage inductance (Henry)
Lr  = Llr + Lm;                  // rotor inductance (Henry)

Rload = Rr/s;                    // rotor resistance for a given slip (Ohm) 
Xls   = 2*%pi*fs*Lls;            // stator leakage reactance (Ohm)
Xlr   = 2*%pi*fs*Llr;            // rotor leakage reactance (Ohm)
Xm    = 2*%pi*fs*Lm;             // magnetizing reactance (Ohm)

// T equivalent circuit solved via the nodal voltage method
// unknown nodal voltages:
// VM - magnetizing branch voltage
// VR - rotor resistance voltage
A = [1/(Rs + %i*Xls) + 1/(%i*Xm) + 1/(%i*Xlr), -1/(%i*Xlr);
                                  -1/(%i*Xlr),  1/(%i*Xlr) + 1/Rload];
B = [VS/(Rs + %i*Xls); 0];
sol = linsolve(A, B);

// magnetizing branch voltage (rms)
VM = sol(1);
// rotor resistance voltage (rms)
VR = sol(2);

// rotor current (rms)
IR = abs((VM - VR)/(%i*Xlr));
// magnetizing current (rms)
IM = abs(VM/(%i*Xm));
// stator current (rms)
IS = IR + IM;
```

I am surprised that the magnitude of the stator current (rms) which I have got for the
slip \$2.48\,\%\$ from the script above is \$447\,\mathrm{A}\$ instead of \$311\,\mathrm{A}\$ (value mentioned in the table). I don't know where is the source of this discrepancy. I think that the equations have been stated correctly because the admittance matrix has the expected symmetry.

Does anybody see where I did a mistake in my calculations? Thanks in advance for any remarks.

**EDIT**:

I have recalculated the script (after cleaning the environment) and I have found that the per phase effective value of the stator current is \$515\,\mathrm{A}\$.

Answer (score 4):

Your Scilab solution may be the peak current rather than the RMS (\$447/311 \approx \sqrt{2}\$) because it is done purely with NVA, meaning there's no time dependency in the equations.

Comment: I wanted to leave this as a comment instead of a full answer because it's not as in-depth as I'd like, but I don't yet have enough reputation to comment

Comment: @S Jin thank you very much for your reaction. Your explanation seems to be very likely. If it's truth it would mean that the nominal line-to-line voltage in the datasheet isn't given as effective value but as amplitude. I thought that nominal voltages/currents are usually expressed as effective values.

Comment: Yeah that's strange, it might be amplitude here -- 420V peak corresponds to 240V RMS, which is a much more common "wall outlet voltage".